# no function after conversion from py to exe

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pycharm, type-conversion

I have written a programme that is controlled with a GUI. in the GUI there is a button and a few input fields, if you press it, a new folder is created that has a few subfolders and a csv file is saved in it with the information from the input fields.

when i run it in pycharme it works without any problems.
but when i want to convert it to an exe with auto-py-to-exe, and then start it, the programme opens but nothing happens when i press the button

## Thats my code

```
def create_folder(EingabeName_text):
    folder_name = EingabeName_text
    folder_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "BHW", folder_name)
    os.mkdir(folder_path)

    briefe_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "_Briefe")
    rechnung_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "_Rechnung")
    ordnerKunde_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "ordner1")
    ordner2_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "ordner2")
    ordner3_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "ordner3")
    ordner4_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "ordner4")

    os.mkdir(briefe_path)
    os.mkdir(rechnung_path)
    os.mkdir(ordnerKunde_path)
    os.mkdir(ordner2_path)
    os.mkdir(ordner3_path)
    os.mkdir(ordner4_path)

    csv_folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, f"{EingabeName_text}.csv")

    with open(csv_folder_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file_briefe:
        fieldnames = ['Kundendaten']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file_briefe, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': EingabeName.get()})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': EingabeStrasse.get()})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': EingabePlzOrt.get()})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': 'Geburtsdatum:'})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': EingabeGeurtstag.get()})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': 'Handynummer:'})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': EingabeHandy.get()})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': 'Rechnungsnummer:'})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': EingabeRnummer.get()})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': 'Informationen:'})
        writer.writerow({'Kundendaten': textbox.get("1.0", "end")})
```

this works in pycharm without any problems.

these are my imports:

import os
import time
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import customtkinter
import customtkinter as ctk
import csv
from PIL import Image

[Image from the tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR5lw.png)

Comment: After creating an exe `__file__` works differently - see https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file for more details.